# Asynctask Integers

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have been trying to work out how to use integers as a parameter in an Asynctask as well as assign the string value i've collected from a parse and put it into a string array to be called upon later. I have looked everywhere and cannot find a solution to this problem.

```
String[] webValues = new String[10];

new parsing().execute("web1", "0");
new parsing().execute("web2", "1");

public class parsing extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>{
    String websiteValues;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            Element itemName = doc.getElementById(params[0]);
            String htmlNoBr = itemName.html().replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
            htmlNoBr = htmlNoBr.replaceAll("<b>", "");
            htmlNoBr = htmlNoBr.replaceAll("</b>", "");
            htmlNoBr = htmlNoBr.replaceAll("<hr>", "");
            websiteValues = htmlNoBr;
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer position) {
        webValues[position.intValue()] = websiteValues;
    }
}
```

I have been able to put the information collected from "web1" when called into a string called webValues when it was not an array, however I am trying to call a 
"new parsing().execute()" where the position of the string array webValues is specified and the information is sent to that index of the string array. Ive been using "Integer" in the Asynctask and trying to assign it using position in the onPostExecute but it hasen't been working. I assume i'm making a rookie mistake and assigning the integer wrong in the execute but ive tried all the ways i could think of and "1" (or any integer value) was the only one not giving me errors. If anyone could point me in the right direction or help me figure out what i'm doing wrong i would greatly appreciate it!

If I haven't explained clearly enough please let me know and I can try to rephrase!

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: AsyncTask prototype is `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` . Where the middle one is for progress and you can not expect it to come out as result, can you ? So assign Result part as Integer type.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this will help you**

```
String[] webValues = new String[10];

new parsing().execute("web1", "0");
new parsing().execute("web2", "1");

public class parsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>{
String websiteValues;
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        Element itemName = doc.getElementById(params[0]); //Here as per your input it first points to web1 and for next web2
        String htmlNoBr = itemName.html().replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
        htmlNoBr = htmlNoBr.replaceAll("<b>", "");
        htmlNoBr = htmlNoBr.replaceAll("</b>", "");
        htmlNoBr = htmlNoBr.replaceAll("<hr>", "");
        websiteValues = htmlNoBr;
        return Integer.parseInt(params[1]); //for first 0 and for second 1
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Integer position) {

    if (position != null)
         webValues[position.intValue()] = websiteValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just added your changes and it didn't work, gave an error:


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference - 

at the public class line, and the webValues[position.intValue()], I thought the doInBackground had to have String not Integer ?

Comment: "web1" and "web2" would be the element Id's on the site, "0" and "1" are suppose to be the indexes of the string array "webValues" that im trying to pass in, so web1 string data would go to index 0, web2 string data to index 1 (i might want it index 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1 considering there isn't an index of 0 . . .whoops)

Comment: Your answer worked after I made a very very small change, I thought I'd let you know, I changed the params[0] in the "return Integer.parseInt(params[0]);" part to a params[1], this way its calling the second parameter. Thank you so much for your help, I wouldn't have gotten it by myself.